# Priority Queue ordering in Java issue

Tags: java, priority-queue

I want to make a priority queue of nodes, wherein priority of nodes is their frequencies. But the output doesn't contain the first element in the right position, rest all are in correct positons.

```
    import java.util.*;
class node implements Comparable<node>{
        char key;
        int freq;
        node(){}
        node(char k,int f){
                key=k;
                freq=f;
        }
    public int compareTo(node n){
            if(freq>n.freq)return 1;
            return 0;
        }
}

public class test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        node x=new node('x',4);
        node a=new node('a',2);
        node b=new node('b',1);
        node c=new node('c',7);
        PriorityQueue<node> q = new PriorityQueue<node>();

        q.offer(a);
        q.offer(b);
        q.offer(c);
        q.offer(x);

        while(!q.isEmpty()){
            node d=q.poll();
            System.out.println(d.key+" "+d.freq);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
    a 2
    b 1
    x 4
    c 7
```

Should not the ordering be b , a, x, c
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your comparator is wrong: if `freq < n.freq`, it returns 0 instead of returning a negative number.

The code should be

```
return Ints.compare(freq, n.freq); // with Guava
```

or

```
return Integer.valueOf(freq).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(n.freq)) // with plain Java
```

or

```
if (freq > n.freq) return 1;
if (freq < n.freq) return -1;
return 0;
```

Comment: then what is the need of returning o?

Comment: 0 is returned when objects are considered equal, i.e. when the frequencies are the same.

Answer (score 2):

Add 
`else if (freq<n.freq) return -1;`

into public int compareTo(node n)